# NSSet with string property from array of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsset

I have an array of somethings, I'd like to make a set from an NSString property on this object:

```
@protocol something<NSObject>

@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *Id;

@end
```

I have an array of somethings:

```
NSArray<id<something>> *arrayOfSomethings;
```

I'd like to get a NSSet of the Id properties:

```
NSSet<NSString *> *idSet = ?; // Calculate from arrayOfSomethings.
```

How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `valueForKey:` to create an array that contains your `id`s and then use that to create an `NSSet`

```
NSSet<NSString *> *idSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[arrayOfSomethings valueForKey:@"id"]];
```